# Akka : Receive call back on actor system shutdown

Tags: scala, event-handling, akka, actor

I need to catch a actor system shutdown event so that i can do some custom clean up.

```
object ChildActor {
  class Msg
}

class ChildActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ : Msg => throw new OutOfMemoryError("error")
  }
}

class ParentActor extends Actor {
  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case _: Error => {
      Stop
    }
    case _: Exception => Stop
  }
  val child = context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor], "child")
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case a : Msg => child ! a
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val customConf = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
  akka {
    jvm-exit-on-fatal-error = false
  }
  """)
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("OOMException", ConfigFactory.load(customConf))
  val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[ParentActor], "parentActor")
  actor ! new Msg
}
```

When i run this app i see following in console :

```
Uncaught error from thread [OOMException-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]: error, shutting down for ActorSystem[OOMException]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: error
    at nl.ing.api.contacting.callflow.business.actor.TestMyActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(TestMyActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive$$$capture(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala)
    at nl.ing.api.contacting.callflow.business.actor.TestMyActor.aroundReceive(TestMyActor.scala:22)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[ERROR] [SECURITY][04/10/2018 11:34:19.177] [OOMException-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(OOMException)] Uncaught error from thread [OOMException-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]: error, shutting down ActorSystem[OOMException]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: error
    at nl.ing.api.contacting.callflow.business.actor.TestMyActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(TestMyActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive$$$capture(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala)
    at nl.ing.api.contacting.callflow.business.actor.TestMyActor.aroundReceive(TestMyActor.scala:22)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

The log says **shutting down for ActorSystem**. Is there any method or call back that i can use to catch this shutdown and call custom clean up code??

**Also when this fatal error is created by child actor then the parent supervision strategy is not called at all**. Any idea why?

TIA!

Comment: Have you tried registerOnTermination method of actor system to run block of code on termination of system.actorSystem.registerOnTermination({cleaunup code})

Comment: i tried that..the call back is not called